# In which situation are those Facebook IOS FBSessionDelegate methods called?

Tags: ios, facebook, fbconnect

It's clear to me that these are called upon login if a user grants or denials permission:

```
- (void)fbDidLogin;
- (void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled;
```

But i was wondering when the following FBSessionDelegate methods could be called:

```
- (void)fbDidExtendToken:(NSString*)accessToken expiresAt:(NSDate*)expiresAt;
- (void)fbDidLogout;
- (void)fbSessionInvalidated;
```

The documentation says:

```
//Called after the access token was extended.
- (void)fbDidExtendToken:(NSString*)accessToken expiresAt:(NSDate*)expiresAt;

//Called when the user logged out. 
- (void)fbDidLogout;

//Called when the current session has expired.
- (void)fbSessionInvalidated;
```

Now when would such a thing happen? When i call the following?

```
[Facebook authorize:nil];
```

There is no chance i will get a fbDidLogout call back right?

Maybe if a user removes my app from his Facebook account via the Facebook app, would this method be called than? No, because my app doesn't open in that case..

**...so in which situation would these be called?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think i found it myself...

**This one:**

```
- (void)fbDidExtendToken:(NSString*)accessToken expiresAt:(NSDate*)expiresAt;
```

Could be called when you call:

```
[facebook extendAccessTokenIfNeeded];
```

**This one:**

```
- (void) fbDidLogout;
```

Gets called when you call

```
[facebook logout] //(of course..)
```

**The last one:**

```
- (void)fbSessionInvalidated;
```

Get's called when you try to send a http request to Facebook with an expired session token.

I found it in the Facebook SDK header file [Facebook.m](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/src/Facebook.m)

I'll leave the question here for anyone looking for the answer :)